# still AND movie shootMode on a6300?

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

Camera: A6300
Remote version: 2.0.1

Is it possible switch between still and movie shootModes remotely? I'm consistently getting back a 500 SET OPERATION FAILED error when trying to switch shoot modes from still to movie and vice versa.

It seems that when "M" (for manual) is selected on the physical dial the only available shootMode that comes back in the API is "still". Similarly when I have the movie icon selected the only available shootMode is "movie". I have an application that requires switching between still and movie recording remotely. Is this possible on the A6300 and of not - is there another camera that supports this type of operation? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This does seem like an interesting problem. Can you show me an example of your json request to the camera? Have you already tried getSupportedShootMode and getAvailableShootMode on each icon setting? Also for setShootMode on some cameras there is a bit more work to be done before you can set the mode. You may need to run the startRecMode call before setting the mode on your camera. Here is the note from the documentation:

> **Special note (details)**
>
> The camera has the concept of shoot mode. Some of APIs are only
>   available on specific shoot mode. For details, see "Supported APIs and
>   available APIs".
>
> Even if the response is successful, the setting may not be finished on
>   the server. Therefore, the client can check "shootMode" object in
>   "getEvent" callback to recognize the timing of a change in the
>   parameter of the server.
>
> ***Some camera models need "startRecMode" API call before accessing
>   camera settings. See "startRecMode" for details.***

Comment: I have called startRecMode which is sucessful, then getSupportedShootMode which returns an array with both "image" and "movie". When I subsequently call getAvailableShootMode it returns an array with a single value, either "image" or "movie" which depends on the position of the hardware dial. I've also tried setShootMode after calling startRecMode which fails. I can post the formatted JSON responses from each tonight.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an RX-10. getSupportedMode returns still and movie, but getAvailableMode only returns a single mode depending on the hardware dial position. Attempting to setShootMode to anything but the current mode results in a 500 internal server error.

Comment: That is correct. The cameras that support the camera API do not support all shoot modes. That is why there are so many functions to check the availability of commands before running them. If you are only getting one shoot mode then that may be the only one you have available. This could also depend on if you have physically set the mode on the camera. Be sure to check to see if your camera has a switch to set the mode.